# How to add aliases for Windows netbeans terminal

Tags: windows, netbeans, terminal

I am using NB on windows and I want to add aliases for the netbeans terminal. Is that possible??I have cygwin and minGW32 installed on my computer. On cygwin, I added aliases in .bash.bash_rc and it works. On mingw32 it also works fine but I can't get it work on NB neither in GitBash.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I just found your question because I needed to solve the same situation.

Type `cd` to go to your home directory.
Then edit the file `.bashrc` using `vi` editor.